# Using London Heathrow's Terminal 3 lounge as a Terminal 5 passenger

Tags: airport-transfer, london, lhr, lounges

I'll have a 3-hour 40-minute layover at LHR Terminal 5. I was wondering if it’s feasible to use the Plaza Premium Lounge at Terminal 3 arrivals (landside). The one at terminal 5 has a 20£ surcharge for using the shower!

How long does it take to go back and forth between Terminal 5 and Terminal 3?

Comment: Unfortunately, it's not possible to access the departures area of a different terminal at Heathrow from the one your flight leaves from; see [Arriving Heathrow airport terminal 2, departing terminal 3, but need lounge access in terminal 2](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/50648/arriving-heathrow-airport-terminal-2-departing-terminal-3-but-need-lounge-acce)

Comment: @gparyani The asker says the lounge they're interested in is _landside_, so it doesn't require access to any departures area.

Comment: I'm not sure how long the transfer is, though T5 is a little way from the other terminals, so I'd guess at least 15 minutes each way. Is it really worth the effort of going through immigration, changing terminals, changing terminals back, going through security again and doing all of that early enough to make sure you catch your connection (e.g., long-haul flights typicaly board about an hour before scheduled departure)? Even with quick transfers, you won't get very long in the T3 lounge.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Possible Yes.   Feasible No.

Assuming that you land on time, and Even if you are fortunate With the the time you need to clear immigration at T5, and then re-clear security and be at the gate in good time for your onward flight

Heathrow T5 to T3 using the free transfer on the train is around 8 to 10 minutes, but there can be a 15 minute wait at some times of the day. There is also a walking tunnel to T3 from the train platform.  I would say at least 30 to 40 minutes each way between terminals.

When I last flew from T5 it took 50 minutes to clear security.

Terminal 5 is a fair distance across the airport from the other parts of the complex, and distance is your enemy.